# Selenium + Python, How to add new tab with url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to

1. Activate the opened window, Let's say fb.com
2. add a new tab with a URL, Let's say google.com

Seems very straightforward, but I am struggling...

Can you please show me how to write a python code for this by using Selenium? (I am a WIndow 10 user btw)

The below code is what I got so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


#PATH = r'C:\Program Files\Chromedriver'
PATH = r'C:\Program Files\IEDriverServer.exe'
driver = webdriver.Ie(PATH)
main_url = "https://www.facebook.com/"
secondary_url = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(main_url)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a new tab with any url and switch to it. Might switch 1 to any number of tabs opened.

```
url='anything'
driver.execute_script("window.open('{0}', '_blank');".format(url))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please help me? Basically I would like to open fb.com and google.com in one browser with two tabs.

Comment: Just put this code after driver.get(main_url) and switch url to the secondary url.